# Passing variable from controller to singleton class and access this variable anywhere

Tags: c#, singleton

I have tried to make use of a singleton class to store the variable of a username from login.

I am getting the username from `Request.QueryString["username"]` in my LoginController.

I have the below class as singleton: My question is how can I pass this `Request.QueryString["username"]`in the singleton class and access this variable anywhere in the application ? I want to access this variable in every controller. Please help.

```
public sealed class Settings
{
    private static Settings instance = null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();

// initialize your variables here. You can read from database for example
Settings()
{
    this.UserName= "prop1"; // I want to push the variable here
}

public static Settings Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Settings();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}

// declare your global variables here
public string UserName{ get; set; }
```

}

Comment: 1. What happens when you have two users? Why are you trying to use a singleton for this? 2. You should ALSO have an `if (instance == null)` check outside your `lock (padlock)` so that you don't have to lock simply to get the existing instance.

Comment: I dont want to use session to store the global variables. I want to go to the singleton approach to store the variable of username. Yes I have multiple users.

Comment: But using a singleton, you can only store a single username at a time. If two requests come in at the exact same time, both requests will use the username that "wins". A singleton isn't unique to a request, it's unique to the application.

Comment: Hmm I see. You are right. 

Could you advise on another alternative to store the username without the use of session ?

Comment: Do you need the username to persist between requests?

Comment: Yes I would need the username to persist.

Comment: Why don't you want to use session? I ask because you could use `HttpContext.Current.Items` to store your singleton object (thus making it per request), but it would only persist for the request. If you need it to persist between requests, you need to use `HttpContext.Current.Session` - which is why I wonder what your reason for not using it is.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to have a user based context (internally done by Session itself)

Create a dictionary object as Dictionary> to store the state. The outer dictionary will hold the userName and inner one will hold the context.

Pseudeo code below

// 1. This dictionary just needs to be initialized in the static constructor.

```
static ctor() {
   stateObject = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>()
}
```

// 2. Have a Login/Logout methods, each taking the userName as parameter.

```
Login(userName) {
   if (stateObject.Keys[userName])   throw new Exception('user already logged in');
   else  stateObject.insert(userName, new Dictionary....)
}

Logout(userName) {
  if (stateObject.Keys[userName])
      stateObject.Remove(userName)
}
```

// 3. Expose a member to get the state as required

```
State(userName, propertyKey) {
     if (stateObject.Keys[userName])
         if (stateObject.Keys[userName].Keys[propertyKey])
             return (stateObject.Keys[userName].Keys[propertyKey])
    else  .. handle exceptions
}
```

The reason you need to pass the userName again here is that you are using Singleton so all instances will be having its access. Session implicitly passes the sessionId but behaves in exactly the same way

Comment: So for every request you have to pass the user's name? Can I pass somebody else's? Session seems slightly better, at least the id isn't easy to guess.

Comment: userName has to be some intrinsic property of the request itself. Rather, here it should be the user's internal id which is difficult to spoof (eg Guid). Sending userName like "nitin.singh" is prone to session hijacking, since its a general alphabetical name anyway.. A guid will be lesser prone, due to its large level of scale

Comment: How do I access the username variable in another controller ?

Comment: Once the user has logged in, the userId has to be stored locally on browser (localStorage), then retrieved in each request and made a part of header. That's how general authentication happens

Comment: How do I retrieve the username ?

Comment: @jones UserName / UserId will be driven from the authentication module of your application. Once login has succeeded, then its output should be a unique user dependent id which is returned. That is to be added to all authorized requests.

Comment: @jones is your original query resolved or you need solutions somewhere else?

Comment: @NitinSingh : I need another alternative